# Laravel 4 Internal Server Error 500 and TokenMismatchException in a HTML Table to update the database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table where I show basic information. It's basically a two-column table with n rows.

In the second column I show a select tag where the user should choose an option (in this case, a country). The corresponding value of the chosen option will be updated in the database through an ajax call.

The problem is that i always get this 500 internal server error and TokenMismatchException. Do i have to use both a form and make use of the `{{ Form::token() }}` ???

My code so far that still have this problem is as follows:

The HTML Table (The view):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Printed Media</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach($medios as $medio)
                            <td>{{$medio->medio}}</td>
                            <td><select class="select2 req_place" placeholder="Elija" data-select-search="true" 
                                id="medio-{{$medio->id}}" name="medio-{{$medio->id}}"
                                style="background-color: gray;">
                                    <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option> 
                                @foreach($paises AS $pais)
                                    <option value="{{$pais->CLAVE}}">{{$pais->PAIS}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
        </div>
     </div>
{{ Form::token() }}
```

I added *{{ Form::token() }}*

The Javascript code is:

```
$('select').change(function(e){
    var id_c = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    var result = id_c.split('-');
    var id = result[1];
    var value = $('#'+id_c).val();
    var url_route = "{{URL::action('DifusionController@post_update_medio')}}";
    var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();
    var datos = { id: id, value: value, _token: _token };
    alert('A country was selected! id: '+id_c + '. Value: '+ value + '. id: '+id);
    alert(url_route); 

    $.post(url_route, datos, function(data,status){
        if(data=='success'){
            alert('Success gotten');
        }
    });
});
```

And my routes **inside the csrf group**:

```
/**** CSRF protection group ****/
Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'),function(){
    /*Update medios*/
    Route::post('/pendientes/medios',array(
        'as'    =>  'post-update-medio',
        'uses'  =>  'DifusionController@post_update_medio'
        ));
    /*Update reporteros*/
    Route::post('/pendientes/reporteros',array(
        'as'    =>  'post-update-reportero',
        'uses'  =>  'DifusionController@post_update_reportero'
        )); 
...
}
```

Inside the controller:

```
public function post_update_medio()
{
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        $token=Request::header('X-CSRF-Token');// : Input::get('_token');
        $id=Input::get('id');
        $value=Input::get('value');

        if(Input::has('id') && Input::has('value'))
        {
            echo 'Medio Posted ☺. ID: '.$id.'. Value: '.$value.' Token: '.$token.' . ';
            /*Update database here*/
            return 'success';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'error';
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        return 'No ajax request';
    }
}
```

And the Chrome inspector returns the following error:

```
error: {type: "Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException", message: "",…}
file: "\MY\PATH\app\filters.php"
line: 179
message: ""
type: "Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException"
```

Must i add a form with token?
How can i fix this?

But **now it works** after editing both the jquery code and the controller.

References:

1. [CSRF tokens when using jQuery Ajax](http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/)
2. [Generating a CSRF token](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/153/generating-a-hidden-field-with-the-csrf-token)

Comment: No you don't need to use a form, but you do need to send the token with your AJAX request, either as a parameter or as a HTTP header. For the second approach you can have a look at [this nice article](https://www.yesdevnull.net/2015/02/using-x-xsrf-token-http-headers-for-ajax-in-laravel-5/).

Comment: And this [one](http://tutsnare.com/post-data-using-ajax-in-laravel-5/)  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a token in your HTML as a hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{csrf_token()}} >
```

And then pass it to your ajax post request as _token

Comment: I tried that and inside the javascript code i added `var _token = $("input[name=_token]").val();` and still get the same error :( . I have found a temporary solution. Check my edit.

Comment: you should not use middleware to bypass this, you can get the value of your token in the html by var token = document.getElementById('token').value;

Comment: All right, i don't bypass it and now i get the 500 internal server error back. Then how do i fix this inside the controller? how do i get the token inside the controller? It doesn't seem to be automatic. :/